# SecretManagerServiceClient in Google Cloud Run and authentication via service account

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I can create a SecretManagerServiceClient without using a key file successfully in Google Cloud Shell:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.exceptions import DefaultCredentialsError
import logging
import sys
import os


def list_secrets(client, project_id):
    """
    Retrieve all secrets associated with a project
    :param project_id: the alpha-numeric name of the project
    :return: a generator of Secrets
    """
    try:
        secret_list = client.list_secrets(request={"parent": "projects/{}".format(project_id)})
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Did not successfully retrieve secret list.")
    return secret_list


def set_env_secrets(client, secret_ids, label=None):
    """
    Sets secrets retrieved from Google Secret Manager in the runtime environment
    of the Python process
    :param secret_ids: a generator of Secrets
    :param label: Secrets with this label will be set in the environment
    """
    for s in secret_ids:
        # we only want secrets with matching labels (or all of them if label wasn't specified)
        if not label or label in s.labels:
            version = client.access_secret_version(request={'name': '{}/versions/latest'.format(s.name)})
            payload_str = version.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
            os.environ[s.name.split('/')[-1]] = payload_str


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient() 
    secrets = list_secrets(client, "myprojectid-123456")
    set_env_secrets(client, secrets)
    print(os.getenv("DATA_DB_HOST"))
```

However, when I use similar code as the basis for an entry point of a container in Google Cloud Run, the attempt to retrieve a client using the default service account's credentials fails with

```
File "entry_point.py", line 27, in get_client
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py", line 274, in __init__
    client_info=client_info,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/transports/grpc.py", line 162, in __init__
    scopes=self.AUTH_SCOPES, quota_project_id=quota_project_id
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 340, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 186, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 97, in load_credentials_from_file
    "File {} was not found.".format(filename)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File  was not found.
```

The default service account has the Editor and Secret Manager Admin roles (thanks to @DanielOcando for his comment). Why is it that the ADC library, as [described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112030550/https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/productionn) does not pick up the permissions of the default service account and use them to instantiate the client?

#### Update 1

@guillaumeblaquiere asked about dependencies. The container is built with Python 3.6.12 and the following libraries:

```
Django==2.1.15
django-admin-rangefilter==0.3.7
django-extensions==2.1.2
django-ipware==1.1.6
pytz==2017.3
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
waitress==1.4.1
geoip2==2.6
gunicorn==19.9.0
social-auth-app-django==3.1.0
semver==2.8.1
sentry-sdk==0.6.9
google-api-core==1.23.0
google-auth==1.23.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0
```

I created a custom service account, added Editor and Secret Manager Admin roles to it, and then used the Console to deploy a new revision with that account, but the same error resulted.

#### Update 2

Thinking that matching the CPython version in Cloud Shell would do the trick, I rebuilt the image with Python 3.7. No luck.

#### Update 3

Taking a different tack, I added Service Account Token Creator role to the default service account of the project and created a terraform file and configured it for service account impersonation. I also ran `gcloud auth application-default login` in the shell prior to invoking terraform.

```
provider "google" {
  alias   = "tokengen"
} 

data "google_client_config" "default" {
  provider = google.tokengen
} 

data "google_service_account_access_token" "sa" {
  provider               = "google.tokengen"
  target_service_account = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
  lifetime               = "600s"
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  ] 
} 

provider "google" {
  project   = "myprojectid-123456"
  region    = "us-central1"
  zone      = "us-central1-f"
  #impersonate_service_account = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
}


resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "myprojectid-123456"
  location = "us-central1"
  
  template {
    spec { 
      containers {
        image = "us.gcr.io/myprojectid-123456/testimage"
      } 
    } 
  } 
  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}
```

This did work to create the service, but again, when the endpoint attempted to instantiate SecretManagerServiceClient, the same error resulted.

Comment: Notice that as stated on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control#least-privilege) the `Editor` role doesn't include `secretmanager.versions.access`. I would recommend you to add the [Secret Manager Secret Accesor](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control#secretmanager.secretAccessor) or the [Secret Manager Admin](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control#secretmanager.admin) role to the [Compute Engine's default service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#runtime_service_account).

Comment: @DanielOcando when I first read your comment, I was so hopeful. You were right, the Compute Engine default service account did _not_ have the Secret Manager permissions in question, but adding Secret Manager Admin did not remedy the situation. Inexplicably, I still receive the same error. My next move will be to create a custom service account and explicitly direct Cloud Run to use that via `gcloud run deploy`

Comment: What's your dependencies version?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've updated the question to list the Python interpreter version and libraries in the container

Comment: I was aware about the new secret manager library in Python but I never tested it. Can you try the `1.0.0` version? Another issue can come from google.auth and google-api-core dependencies, which is also use in secret manager dependencies, and there is a possible conflict. Try to remove them.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I eliminated the extraneous libraries and downgraded the version of `google-cloud-secret-manager` to `1.0.0`. No effect--same error.

Comment: Can you share how you deploy your Cloud Functions? Do you set environment variables? If so, can you list them?